# Request Validation asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Tenho um TextBox que usa o editor de texto ckeditor. Quando executo o método para salvar as informações, da um erro

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$fTxtConteudo="
>
> sdgfdsgdg
>
> ").
>   Description: ASP.NET has detected data in the request that is potentially dangerous because it might include HTML markup or script. The data might represent an attempt to compromise the security of your application, such as a cross-site scripting attack. If this type of input is appropriate in your application, you can include code in a web page to explicitly allow it. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=212874. 
>   Exception Details: System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$fTxtConteudo="
>
> sdgfdsgdg
>
> ").

Já coloque o código no <@ Page validateRequest="false" %> e mesmo assim não funcionou.
Quero aplicar esta permissão somente nesta pagina, e não no site inteiro através no web.config

Lembrando que estou usando asp.net

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer o trabalho para `ValidateRequest` em .Net 4.0 ou versões superiores, você vai precisar adicionar a seguinte configuração no `web.config`, seção `<system.web>`:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Uma vez adicionado, você pode definir `validateRequest=false` no `web.config` ou na diretiva `Page`.

Answer (score 0):

Na diretiva da sua página, coloque o seguinte código setando o ValidateRequest para *false*.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="StackOverflowWEB._Default" ValidateRequest="false" %>
```